# OSM API returns different values with and without debug mode

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

If you use the Nominatim API from Open Street Map, once in debug mode and once without debug mode you get different data.

Example URLs:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=51.06810&lon=8.79765&zoom=18&format=jsonv2&debug=1

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=51.06810&lon=8.79765&zoom=18&format=jsonv2

Important for me is especially the 'website' field, which is present in debug mode, but not otherwise.

How can I get all the data?

Comment: Nitpick: please don't use the term "OSM API" for Nominatim. When people talk about OSM API, they typically mean this one: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extratags to get this data:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse.php?lat=51.06810&lon=8.79765&zoom=18&format=jsonv2&extratags=1